# How to Keep CupertinoDatePicker at the Bottom of the Screen Instead of the Whole Screen?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

So, I implemented a CupertinoDatePicker into my app, but when I try to access it, it shows up on the whole screen, rather than just the bottom.

Here is the code:

```
onPressed: () {
 showCupertinoModalPopup(
 context: context,
 builder: (BuildContext context) => CupertinoDatePicker(
  mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.dateAndTime,
  onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime date) {
   _dateTime = date;
   }),
  );
},
```

I'm wondering why this is the case. The reference docs don't really help either.

Comment: You can use `ActionSheet` instead. https://medium.com/flutterpub/actionsheet-in-flutter-13b1087987f0

Answer (score 7):

Try this :

```
    class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
    }

    class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

    // Value that is shown in the date picker in dateAndTime mode.
    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.now();
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Center(
            child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
                showCupertinoModalPopup<void>(
                context: context,
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return _buildBottomPicker(
                    CupertinoDatePicker(
                        mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.dateAndTime,
                        initialDateTime: dateTime,
                        onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime newDateTime) {
                        if (mounted) {
                            print("Your Selected Date: ${newDateTime.day}");
                            setState(() => dateTime = newDateTime);
                        }
                        },
                    ),
                    );
                },
                );
            },
            child: Text('show date picker'),
            ),
        ),
        );
    }
        double _kPickerSheetHeight = 216.0;
        Widget _buildBottomPicker(Widget picker) {
            return Container(
            height: _kPickerSheetHeight,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 6.0),
            color: CupertinoColors.white,
            child: DefaultTextStyle(
                style: const TextStyle(
                color: CupertinoColors.black,
                fontSize: 22.0,
                ),
                child: GestureDetector(
                // Blocks taps from propagating to the modal sheet and popping.
                onTap: () {},
                child: SafeArea(
                    top: false,
                    child: picker,
                ),
                ),
            ),
            );
        }

    }
```

[image]

Comment: That's great! How did you record that video snippet?

Comment: is it possible in angular 8 ?

Comment: @NareshEtikala I'm not sure, may be this will help you https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nativescript/datetimepicker

Comment: What does `mounted` refer to? `onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime newDateTime) { if (mounted) {...`

Comment: Wow! NM. I was wondering why `mounted` wasn't throwing an error in VS Code, so I hovered over it. From IntelliSense: `bool get mounted` | `package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart` | Whether this [State] object is currently in a tree. After creating a [State] object and before calling [initState], the framework "mounts" the [State] object by associating it with a [BuildContext]. The [State] object remains mounted until the framework calls [dispose], after which time the framework will never ask the [State] object to [build] again. It is an error to call [setState] unless [mounted] is true.